# Get the points coordinates from a geometry projection over a Solid in Autodesk Inventor with VBA

Tags: vba, 3d, point, point-clouds, autodesk-inventor

I would like to get the coordinates (in a text or Excel file) of a set of points that are produced after projecting another set of points over a solid (All this done using the software Autodesk Inventor Professional 2016).
I would like to do this with VBA automatically since I intend to do it with many points.
For the moment I have found examples on how to create workpoints on a sketch and how to export the workpoints coordinates into an Excel file (I add a link of a source with a solution below) but I am not able to get the coordinates of the points that are created with the projection (the actual points in the surface of the solid) since it seems that they are not considered as points by Inventor. To get those points I use the "Project Geometry" tool.

Is there any way to do this with VBA?

It would also help me if somebody could tell me how to convert the surface of a solid into a point cloud or how to convert this points that are produced with the projection into WorkPoints (so I can use the code I have already).

Link that presents a solution to export points coordinates:

http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/inventor-customization/unable-to-export-3d-point-co-ordinates-data-to-excel/td-p/6295396

I am not currently able to share more links with other sources I have found (in this post).

I have also added a link to an image to illustrate what I am doing.

[Image of what I am doing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5wjw.png)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I just created a blog post that hopefully answers your question about projecting the points onto a solid.

http://modthemachine.typepad.com/my_weblog/2016/06/projecting-points-onto-a-solid.html

Regarding your second question about getting the solid as a point cloud; it is possible.  You'll want to look at the CalculateFacets, CalculateFacetsWithOptions, and GetExistingFacets methods.  These all do the same thing in that they return a set of points that represent a triangle approximation of the solid.